# Only Having a Pop-up After All Questions Are Answered

Tags: popup, logic, survey, redcap

I have three Y/N questions in my REDCap survey and I'm trying to make it so that if they say no to any of the three questions, a pop-up shows **after** they fill out all of the three questions. Is there any way to do this without having to use branching logic for all the combinations of Y/Y/N?

I've looked up similar problems and haven't found anything that was similar to my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

1. By "pop-up" you're referring to a descriptive text field shown/hidden by branching logic
2. Your three y/n fields are coded `1, Yes | 0, No`
3. Your fields are named (for the purpose of this example) `[q1]`, `[q2]`, `[q3]`

Branching logic to have the descriptive text field displayed when all three questions have a response, and at least one is "No", would be this:

```
[q1]<>'' and [q2]<>'' and [q3]<>'' and sum([q1],[q2],[q3])<3
```